# MySQL Query to get student grades AND class average

Tags: mysql, database

I am fairly new to the world of SQL and am finding the syntax a tad bit awkward to work with while I try to understand how joins and such work. I am practicing by building a small web app that lets you pick a date and possibly a name of a student (if none is defined then all students are shown). My idea is that basically multiple tables (one per student) will be generated off of a given query and it would show the student's name and other related info, along with this it also will show the average grade of all the students along side that specific students information. However, I am not sure how to actually make a query that will return all the students, those with and without grades on a given date, alongside the overall average of that test/quiz on said date.

The tables I am working with are student which has a student_id, name and sex. An Event table that has an event_id, type (test or quiz) and a date. And finally a score table that has an event_id, student_id and a score.

Essentially the resulting query would return a table with these columns.

|  student_id  |  Name  |  Date  |  Type  | Grade  |  Class Avg  |

every row is a unique student, the date the given test or quiz was taken on, the grade they got (if they took test/quiz, otherwise it's NULL) and then the class avg for that test/quiz. I know how to get everything up to the class average. I'm not even sure if it is or isn't possible without doing 2 queries or to calculate it myself while rendering the webpage.

Comment: I posted a code snippet from one my our forms feel free to play around with it and let me know if you run into any problems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42932220/which-technologies-to-use-for-forms-created-dynamically

Comment: DON'T CREATE TABLES ON THE FLY. The DB structure should be fixed and only data is added during the life time of your app/site.

Comment: And what is the question actually?

Comment: Given a query the returns the grade all students got, NULL or otherwise, can you have an additional column within the query that also depicts the class average?

Comment: Also why would I not create tables on the fly, is that not the whole point of using a relational database?

Comment: I think I see what you meant @juergend, I am not dynamically building new tables for my database, I am building HTML tables that are being displayed on a web page based on query results